# Can not compare dates properly using Angular.js/Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I need one help.I am unable to compare the selected date with today's date using Angular.js or JavaScript.I am explaining my code below.

```
var today=new Date();
console.log('2 dates',today,$scope.date);
```

From the above console i am getting the output like below.

```
2 dates Fri Jun 03 2016 18:29:16 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) 03-06-2016

if(today > new Date($scope.date.split("-").reverse().join(","))){
    alert('Please select  future delivery date');
}
```

Here i need suppose my selected date is `03-06-2016` and today's date is `03-06-2016` the alert prompt should not come.But in my case  its not happening like this.This alert message is coming also if selected date is `03-06-2016`. Here i need the alert message should come  if selected date is more than today's date only.Please help me.

Comment: Are you stripping time out of the dates? Accounting for timezone differences? What do you get if you console log the dates inside your if statement?

Comment: If you have a lot of date logic to include and can use plugins - I'd recommend `momentjs`

Comment: I have already printed the log messages.`today` is giving the todays date time and `$scope.date` is my selected date.

Comment: @ tymeJV : Here todays date is including while comparing but i need  to compare with future date instead of todays date for that alert message.

Comment: string manipulation of dates is risky and error-prone, which is why everyone's knee-jerking moment.js at you.  That's not the source of your problem here, though; you have an off-by-one error on the month.

Comment: ok,can you share your solution for this.

Comment: I have. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't compare JavaScript dates using native < or > operators; install and use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) - it will handle all the difficulties for you:

```
if(moment(new Date()).isAfter(moment($scope.date, "MM-DD-YYYY"), 'day')) { ...
```

Comment: but my code is working but not working as per my requirement.

Comment: @subhra in other words, your code is not working correctly. The above solution is intended to make it work.

Comment: @DmitriyKhudorozhkov momentjs is great, but would not work as written in your answer: `moment($scope.date)` throws 'Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release'  and returns an "Invalid date" because $scope.date is not in a format momentjs accepts.

Comment: @DanielBeck you can use it this way, then: moment($scope.date, "MM-DD-YYYY");

Comment: Thank you for that.

Comment: @DmitriyKhudorozhkov : i did also as per you its not working at all.

Comment: @subhra - then all we can count on is a short plunkr showing the problem :)

Comment: @DmitriyKhudorozhkov : Can you create a plunkr demo for this.Put selected date static as i mentioned.

Comment: @subhra that's rather presumptuous. If you're not willing to put in the bare minimum effort to help us understand where you're going wrong, people are unlikely to want to continue trying to help you. Just saying "it's not working" without explanation doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: @DanielBeck : I have explained my requirement many times here and i am doing as per you people's comment but not getting the proper output.

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Months are zero-indexed when constructing Dates:

```
console.log(new Date(2016,06,03));

"2016-07-03T04:00:00.000Z" // you expected June, but got July.
```

Note also that that is set to midnight: any `new Date()` run during the same day will be greater than that value.

String manipulation of dates is risky and error-prone, which is why everyone's knee-jerking momentjs at you (it is in fact a very good library and worth using if you're doing much date manipulation).

At the least, you may want to consider using a less ambiguous date format in `$scope.date`, but if you're stuck with that, in this case, you need to  subtract 1 from the month when constructing a `Date` from it:

```js
// this sample code will only work correctly on June 3 2016 :)

    var $scope = {
      date: "03-06-2016", // I am assuming DD-MM-YYYY format here
      tomorrow: "04-06-2016"
    };
    var today = new Date();

    // test against today:
    var dArr = $scope.date.split('-');
    var testDate = new Date(dArr[2],dArr[1]-1,dArr[0]);
    
    if (today > testDate) {
      console.log("today is greater than testDate."); 
     /* Note that anytime during today will be greater than the zero
        o'clock constructed from $scope.date.  If what you really want
        is to alert only on the following day, then add 1 to the day 
        of $scope.date when converting it to a Date(). */
    }

    // now test against tomorrow:
    dArr = $scope.tomorrow.split('-');
    testDate = new Date(dArr[2],dArr[1]-1,dArr[0]);
    
    if (today < testDate) {
      console.log("today is less than (tomorrow's) testDate.");
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether $scope.date is MM-DD-YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY -- this is the problem with ambiguous date formats.  Whichever of those is the month, subtract one from it, that should work.

Comment: @subhra - then it'd be very helpful if you can create a short plunckr replicaing the problem.

Comment: @DanielBeck : suppose i selected `03-06-2016` and todays date is also `03-06-2016` how it became greater .Please check your code.

Comment: I have added more demonstration code and explanation; @subhra I suspect the fact that `new Date()`  includes the time of day may also have been an issue for you here...

Comment: @DanielBeck : Dont compare with tomorrows date.Because user will select any date that will compare with only todays date.

Comment: I included that only to demonstrate how date comparisons are working.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to `timestamp` to compare it:

```
$scope.date = '2016-06-01';
var currentDate = new Date().valueOf();
var date = new Date($scope.date).valueOf();

if (currentDate > date) {
  // something
}
```

It you use `multi timezone`, please convert both to a `timezone`.

Comment: Make sure you using AngularJS. If not, update `$scope.date` to a JavaScript variable.